# Add to favourites function [swift]

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uibutton

I have a `UITableView` in which i am populating data from core data. The `TableViewCell` consists of some labels and a favourite button. I want that, when  user clicks the `button` the entire cell is added to a different favourite table view controller class, which can be accessed from the Favourite tab.
Just like in stock iphone "Phone" app. When the user adds a contact to favorites it is visible under the favourite tab.
How can i achieve this in swift ?
Please guide me and point me in the right direction.

I was thinking of something like, adding the cell data to a different core data model on the click of the `button`. Then using this model to populate the cells in favourite table view controller class.
But i am new to swift and dont know how to implement this idea. Any kind of help will be much appreciated.

Comment: How you are handling the favorites for different users? I mean multiple users logged into the same device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you already have CoreData entity that you use to populate the table view. You could add a new attribute of type bool to it that indicates if the item is a favorite. Let's call it for example `isFavorite`. Then in your Favorite tab you use CoreData to populate the favorites table the same way as you populate your main table, but you create the CoreData query with a predicate `isFavorite == true`...

Comment: How can i save the user's preferences ? Suppose when the user clicks the favourite button the value of `isFavorite` changes from false to true. How can i save this change so that when the user launches the app again, the value remains the same ?

Comment: I m stuck here now. Please check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32326523/how-to-update-existing-object-in-core-data-swift)