# Unable to update core data object

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, insert

I able to insert,find,delete the core data object but unable to update the existing core data object.
StudentTable is the entity. id,rollnumber,classnumber,classid,classname are the attributes.

I had created *NSEntityDescription* , *NSFetchRequest* , *NSPredicate* but still data is not getting updated to existing core data object.
The whole object is getting deleted when the update button is pressed, which I have no idea how.

Update button action code

```
@IBAction func update(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if(id.text != nil)
    {

        let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "StudentTable", in: managedObjectContext)

        let request: NSFetchRequest<StudentTable> = StudentTable.fetchRequest()
        request.entity = entityDescription

        let pred = NSPredicate(format: "(id = %@)", id.text!)
        request.predicate = pred

        let studenttable = StudentTable(entity: entityDescription!, insertInto: managedObjectContext)

        do {
            var results =
                try managedObjectContext.fetch(request as! NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>)

            if results.count > 0 {
                let match = results[0] as! NSManagedObject

                match.setValue(String(describing: id.text), forKey: "id")
                match.setValue(Int(rollnumber.text!), forKey: "rollnumber")
                match.setValue(Int(classnumber.text!), forKey: "classnumber")
                match.setValue(Int(classid.text!), forKey: "classid")
                match.setValue(String(describing: classname.text!), forKey: "classname")

                do {
                    try managedObjectContext.save()
                    beacondataobject.append(studenttable)

                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "updated data", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
                    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print("Could not save  \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
                }

            } else {
                //noting found
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "No data found", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Search Again", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

        } catch let error {
            print("error %@", error)
        }

    }
    else{

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Enter id to search", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Try Again", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

Any suggestion will appreciated, thank you.

using xcode 8.2, swift 3

Comment: Try this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32326523/how-to-update-existing-object-in-core-data-swift?rq=1

Comment: It didnt solved my problem @sneha In my case the whole object is getting deleted instead of inserting.

Comment: What is your goal with the object `studenttable`? You appear to create it, but then never access it or change any of it attributes.  Other than `studenttable` is there anywhere else that you insert records?

Comment: When user searches for the record in StudentTable it gets displayed in the text fields, if values are changed and update button is pressed then I need to change that specific value.